# Column does not allow nulls. INSERT Fails : SQL R services

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

following is a sample of my SQL table:

```
Id  A   B   Gradient
--------------------
1   2   4   0
1   3   5   0
1   4   6   0
1   1   7   0
1   2   8   0
2   3   4   0
2   4   3   0
2   5   2   0
2   6   4   0
```

To compute the gradient and insert the values in the column `Gradient` I use the following code:

```
INSERT INTO DB.dbo.Table (Gradient)
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R' 
    , @script = N'

         library(dplyr)

        OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet %>%
          group_by(Id) %>%
          mutate(Gradient = (lead(A)-lag(A))/(lead(B)-lag(B)))
  %>% data.frame() %>% select(c(Gradient))'

    , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM Table;'
```

I am using the R Services within the SQL Server and when I execute the query, I get the following error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 107
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'DB.dbo.Table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I do not understand why I am getting this error as I am not inserting this into the `Id` column.

Note: Here's some schema info of the Table

```
COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_DEFAULT  IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id          1                   NULL            NO          uniqueidentifier
A           2                   NULL            NO          decimal
B           3                   NULL            NO          decimal
Gradient    4                   NULL            YES         decimal
```

Comment: Based on what you did post, we see your table has 3 columns that are **not** nullable. You are populating only 1 (gradient) of those columns during the insert - and that causes the error. Perhaps you intended to update the existing rows?

Comment: @SMor No, I just need to update the values in the column `Gradient` which are calculated using the values of column `A` and `B`

Comment: Is there a reason why this is being done using r?

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia So the answer to my question is yes? As Martin wrote - you have an insert statement, not an update statement. I've seen posts that use openquery with a loop-back linked server which might work here. Otherwise, Martin's suggestions seems easiest and less fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is using `INSERT INTO DB.dbo.Table`

This is the reason you are getting issues - you are not, as I suspect you want to do, applying an `UPDATE` to the existing data.

I'm not sure on the R syntax, but it also looks like you are only returning the Gradient value?

I think you will need to return ALL the columns and INSERT those to a Temp table and then JOIN that back to the original.

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to store it in a temporary table and then join. Thank you